# how to access the configuration data from within a controller action?

Tags: zend-framework

I have place this on my application.ini file:

```
contact.email.address = "my.mail@bla.org"
contact.email.name = "Test Name"
```

Then on my index controller action I have done:

```
$configOptions = $this->getInvokeArg('bootstrap')->getOptions();
$contactAddress = $configOptions->contact.email.address;
$this->view->contact = $contactAddress;
```

On my view I have:

`var_dump($this->contact);` but I'm receiving NULL.

What am I missing ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In your controller, I think you want:

```
$configOptions = $this->getInvokeArg('bootstrap')->getOptions();
$contactAddress = $configOptions['contact']['email']['address'];
$this->view->contact = $contactAddress;
```

Comment: Or: `$configOptions = new Zend_Config($this->getInvokeArg('bootstrap')->getOptions());` and then: `$configOptions->contact->email->address;` - my bad syntax errors... :((

Comment: Right, I usually create this `Zend_Config` instance during `Bootstrap` and save it someplace so that I can access it later using the cleaner syntax you identify here.

Comment: Yeah, I usually save the Zend_Config instance using the Zend_Registry

Answer (score 2):

You can use:

```
$configOptions = new Zend_Config($this->getInvokeArg('bootstrap')->getOptions());
$contactAddress = $configOptions->contact.email.address;
$this->view->contact = $contactAddress;
```